# Using vue transition with multiple v-show

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-transitions

I'm using the following code to show a skeleton loader and when it's completed, it needs to fade out while the other div fades in, in it's place.

```
<transition name="fade" mode="out-in">
  <b-skeleton-table
    v-show="showSkeletons"
    :rows="5"
    :columns="4"
    :table-props="{ bordered: true, striped: true }"
  />

  <div v-show="showPageContent">
    <slot name="content" />
  </div>

  <div v-show="showEmptyState">
    <slot name="empty-state" />
  </div>
</transition>
```

I am forced to use v-show because the content slot sometimes contains a table with data, that emits a value whether the table returned has 0 rows or more.
Based on that result I want to show the empty state or not.

But documentation states that transitions cannot be used with multiple and requires a v-if directive.
Since v-if doesn't render the data inside, I cannot use this because I need the emitted data from the content slot.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are attempting to transition multiple elements, I think you may need to look at using a [transition-group](https://vuejs.org/guide/built-ins/transition-group.html).

[Here is a StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-8mo4bu?file=src/App.vue) that will hopefully provide some inspiration for you. You should be able to swap the `v-show` to use `v-if` (if) you need that functionality.